# Event Handler vs using a delegate

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

I have a singleton that I share among a bunch of different threads. Some times one thread needs to communicate with another.

I was thinking of two approaches:

Each thread puts a delegate in the singleton. When the time is necessary one thread calls a function in the singleton which calls the other delegate in the singleton which notifies each thread to do something.

The other option is using the standard eventhandling mechanism.

Is there a benefit to using one or the other?

Comment: What exactly is the point of the singleton here?

Comment: Neither a delegate nor an event handler could pass control from one thread to another. I am sure that I am missing something here: what are you planning to do inside the delegate/event to make other threads do things?

Comment: It pretty much is just a global variable to different classes can communicate with each other.

Comment: Remember, an `event` is just a special kind of `delegate`.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of which thread has registered a delegate with the singleton (or added an event to the singleton, it does not matter) the notification **will happen in the context of the notifying thread**.

If you need to make one thread do things as directed by another thread, you need to communicate that intent with data. For example, each thread could set up a blocking queue, and wait for items to be pushed into their queue by others. These items could be delegates, objects, or pure data items that need to be interpreted before taking an action. The important thing is that in order for the action to happen in a thread, the thread itself must execute that action.

Comment: I totally agree, the new ConcurrentQueue in .net 4 would be perfect. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx. Each thread should have their own queue to read from. If the scheduler thread want to assign special work for  the worker threads. I would really rethink the usage of threads and more look at Tasks.

Answer (score 3):

The standard eventing system will work better for you if that's what you want (and it sounds like it does), why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

I would think that standard events will be more familiar to people looking at the code, and I would guess that it would be more performant. Is that an issue? Have you tried perf-testing it?